# How to animate and rotate a button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIButton` and two `UILabels` around it. Right now, when you tap on the button, the two labels animate and inter-change their position. In addition to this happening, I want to animate and rotate the button 180 degrees and then back to the original position as the labels change position. How can I do this?

Here the code for the button click handler -

```
NSIndexPath *homeToWorkCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *homeToWorkCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:homeToWorkCellIndexPath];
    UILabel *homeLabel = (UILabel *)[homeToWorkCell viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *switchButton = (UIButton *)[homeToWorkCell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *workLabel = (UILabel *)[homeToWorkCell viewWithTag:3];

    CGRect homeLabelRectFrame = homeLabel.frame;
    CGRect workLabelRectFrame = workLabel.frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        homeLabel.frame = workLabelRectFrame;
        workLabel.frame = homeLabelRectFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // will switch the pickup points here
        NSString *currentFromPickupPointId = _fromPickupPointId;
        NSString *currentToPickupPointId = _toPickupPointId;

        _fromPickupPointId = currentToPickupPointId;
        _toPickupPointId = currentFromPickupPointId;
    }];
```

I would ideally like to do this animation in this method but I do not have much experience in animations as I am new to iOS dev.

EDIT:
As mentioned in the answers I tried changing my button tap handler to -

```
NSIndexPath *homeToWorkCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *homeToWorkCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:homeToWorkCellIndexPath];
    UILabel *homeLabel = (UILabel *)[homeToWorkCell viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *switchButton = (UIButton *)[homeToWorkCell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *workLabel = (UILabel *)[homeToWorkCell viewWithTag:3];

    CGRect homeLabelRectFrame = homeLabel.frame;
    CGRect workLabelRectFrame = workLabel.frame;

    // animation for the labels
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        homeLabel.frame = workLabelRectFrame;
        workLabel.frame = homeLabelRectFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // will switch the pickup points here
        NSString *currentFromPickupPointId = _fromPickupPointId;
        NSString *currentToPickupPointId = _toPickupPointId;

        _fromPickupPointId = currentToPickupPointId;
        _toPickupPointId = currentFromPickupPointId;
    }];

    // animation block for the button
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        switchButton.transform = transform;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        switchButton.transform = transform;
    }];
```

This does animate the button rotation. But the animation of the interchange of the labels does not happen anymore. Not sure what is happening here.

Please let me know if something in not clear in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this animation block for the button alongwith the rest of your code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 //half the label animation duration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                     switchButton.transform = transform;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     switchButton.transform = transform;
                 }];
```

### EDIT:

If you're interchanging the the labels by frame then remove `AutoLayout` on your custom `UITableViewCell` <sup>**(Xib > File Inspector > (Uncheck) Use Autolayout)**</sup>

## **But...**

If want to continue using `AutoLayout` on the `UITableViewCell`, and you should, then you need to change the label constraints rather than the frame.

To do it via Constraint changes:

1. Put constraints on the `view`s
2. Make Outlet connections for the necessary constraints with `NSLayoutConstraint` objects
3. Modify the constraint's `constant` parameter
4. Call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the view that holds these constraints

### Example (*in Autolayout via XIB*):

In the **`.h`** of your Custom `UITableViewCell` class (*that I've named `CustomCell`*)

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *btnTest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *txtF_1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *txtF_2;

//----txtF_1 constraints
//Leading Constraint
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_1_left;
//Trailing Constraint
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_1_right;

//----txtF_2 constraints
//Leading Constraint
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_2_left;
//Trailing Constraint
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_2_right;

@end
```

---

**Example `XIB` looks like:**

[image: XIB]

---

**Connecting an `NSLayoutConstraint` outlet:**

[image: Constraint Outlet]

---

**`txtF_1` Constraints Overview:**

[image: txtF_1]

---

**`txtF_2` Constraints Overview:**

[image: txtF_2]

---

Your `tableViewController` methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell"
                                              owner:nil
                                            options:nil]
                objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell.txtF_1 setText:@"left"];
    [cell.txtF_2 setText:@"right"];

    [cell.btnTest addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(btnTestAct:event:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

---

```
-(void)btnTestAct:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //backup constraints
    NSInteger i_left = cell.constraint_1_left.constant;
    NSInteger i_right = cell.constraint_1_right.constant;
    //swap constraints
    cell.constraint_1_left.constant = cell.constraint_2_left.constant;
    cell.constraint_1_right.constant = cell.constraint_2_right.constant;
    cell.constraint_2_left.constant = i_left;
    cell.constraint_2_right.constant = i_right;

    CGFloat f_animationTime = 0.3;

    //textField animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:f_animationTime
                     animations:^{
                         //animate constraint changes
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];

    //button animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:f_animationTime/2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                         sender.transform = transform;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         sender.transform = transform;
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Do I add this code in addition to the animation I already have or do I have to merge them? I tried adding this animation block in addition to what I have (after the label interchange animation), and the label interchange animation stopped working.

Comment: @Siddharth : no you don't need to merge the animation blocks. in my case, i am able to animate both blocks concurrently without any effort. update your question with the solution provided here and lets see what's happening

Comment: I have updated my question with the code that you have suggested but the labels do not interchange now!

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how to change the constraints of the labels to interchange their position. Can you please give me a pointer here?

Comment: @Siddharth : updated answer with Autolayout example. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(45));

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

don't forget to define:
     #define degreesToRadians(degrees) (M_PI * degrees / 180.0)

Comment: Do I add this in addition to the code that I have? Or do I need to somehow merge this? I am finding that having two animations does not work. See the other answer by @staticVoidMan